# How to obtain Access Token using production environment in DocuSign?

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

In Docusing I am obtained access token with demo account successfully and create envelope also, when I move to production account, I can't get access token and got error as "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." I did 20 API calls successfully and reviewed and make Go to live from developer account, API key details reflects on production login also.

Old Code
This is the code I used to obtain access token.

```vb
Dim PrivateKey As String = odjDTRep.Rows(0)("PrivateKey").ToString().Trim.Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "")
'This section to generate jwt Header
Dim ar1 As JObject = New JObject()
ar1.Add("typ", "JWT")
ar1.Add("alg", "RS256")

Dim header As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ar1.ToString)


'This section to generate jwt Body
Dim ar2 As JObject = New JObject()
ar2.Add("iss", odjDTRep.Rows(0)("iss_Int_Key").ToString())

ar2.Add("sub", odjDTRep.Rows(0)("sub1_Api_UserName").ToString())
ar2.Add("iat", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), Now().ToUniversalTime))
ar2.Add("exp", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 1, Now().ToUniversalTime)))
ar2.Add("aud", odjDTRep.Rows(0)("aud").ToString())' aud i pass account.docusign.com
ar2.Add("scope", odjDTRep.Rows(0)("scope").ToString())
Dim body As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ar2.ToString)
Dim stringToSign As String = header & "." & body

Dim bytesToSign() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)
Dim keyBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKey)
Dim privKeyObj = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(keyBytes)
Dim privStruct = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(privKeyObj)

'This section to generate jwt Signature
Dim sig As ISigner = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA")
sig.Init(True, New RsaKeyParameters(True, privStruct.Modulus, privStruct.PrivateExponent))
sig.BlockUpdate(bytesToSign, 0, bytesToSign.Length)
Dim signature() As Byte = sig.GenerateSignature()

Dim sign As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature)

Dim a As String = header & "." & body & "." & sign
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=" & a & "")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.ContentLength = 0

request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{ ""Username"":""" & odjDTRep.Rows(0)("UserName").ToString() & """,  ""Password"":""" & odjDTRep.Rows(0)("Password").ToString() & """,  ""IntegratorKey"":""" & odjDTRep.Rows(0)("iss_Int_Key").ToString() & """ }")
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Console.WriteLine((CType(response, HttpWebResponse)).StatusCode)

If (CType(response, HttpWebResponse)).StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
    Return "002:Fail"
End If

Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
reader.Close()
response.Close()
```

All details I read from SQL table and store in DataTable, from DataTable I pass all details in that code. Any other URL I need change above I mention for production environment?

New code to obtain Access token

```
 var apiCent = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
        string ik = "xxxx-6a8b-4a7d-ba0f-xxxx";
        string userId = "xxxxx-db97-xxx-a398-0e5986fadf49";
        string accountId = "xxxxx-3e10-42af-xxxxx-xxxx";
        string envId = "";
        string authserver = "account.docusign.com";
        string rsaKey = "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";
        var scopes = new List<string>
        {
            "signature"
        };
        OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiCent.RequestJWTUserToken(ik, userId, authserver,Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsaKey), 1, scopes);
        string accessToken = authToken.access_token;
```

Now i am getting error as "Unexpected PEM type" , in production account i take IK,UserID and generated new RSA key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [using legacy auth is not allowed](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/oauth2-requirements-migration/) for new applications. You are using the X-DocuSign-Authentication header with clear text password which is a legacy mechanism to authenticate. **It is insecure and cannot be used**.

When using [JWT authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) and changing from the developer environment to the production environment you have to do the following:

1. Pass [go-live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/) and get approval to have your IK (app) in production.
2. Promote your IK to your production account.
3. Create a new RSA key for the new IK in the production account. You cannot use the RSA key from your developer account.
4. The URL for authentication is changed from https://account-s.docusign.com to https://account.docusign.com
5. userId for the user will be different GUID - need to update
6. accountId for the account will be different GUID - need to update

Comment: Now i am getting error as "Unexpected PEM type" , in production account i take IK,UserID and generated new RSA key.  Ss -https://prnt.sc/OzsuRYIJvOah, i updated new code in above description, for security reason i hide few thing from that keys.

Comment: rsa key is a multi-line string that has to be entered exactly as you got it. Best to read it from a file. I don't think the way you have it would work because there are no line-breaks

Comment: i read key like this Dim rsaKey As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("") & "/Key/Key.txt") , i copy and paste what i get in RSA , except i removed -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- lines.still i am getting same error, what type of file  need to save key file ? txt or pem ? i pass key directly also got error. pls reply asap

Comment: file must contains both public and private key in pem file ?

Comment: don't remove anything!

Comment: just private key, but don't remove any line or any single character!

Comment: hi , i am getting "'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. " if i include -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----  Ss -https://prnt.sc/hHRGQTlJppC5  private key Ss -https://prnt.sc/Q46F3K-xtqmH. And i am using ordinary ASP.net with vb language.i am not use .net core or mvc

Comment: what type file need to create for key ? .pem or .txt or .key ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it just have to be a text file, but you can call it private.key

Comment: you don't use base64 encoding to read the private key

Comment: You need to read it as it is

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes(path) - this is the code you need to read the key, where path is the path of the file on your disk

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, it worked with developer account, when i use production account details i get this error  DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"no_valid_keys_or_signatures"}'
Code Ss - https://prnt.sc/yCDuHdpJZFYA , is the production url is correct ? i generated new RSA from production login

Comment: Did you set the IK/RSA key in production? did you get consent for the user/IK in production?

Comment: yes i set IK and new RSA in production and i did consent manually with this url
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=xxxx-xxx-4a7d-xxx-77612aa344c4&redirect_uri=http://localhost/default.aspx

Comment: url Ss- https://prnt.sc/KvkrnpwIQC2f

Comment: So, the IK and the key are from production?

Comment: "error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"no_valid_keys_or_signatures"
This error suggests that the IK you use in production doesn't have a valid RSA key, or that you didn't provide the correct RSA key when you made the call

Comment: Yes correct, its from prodction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243351/discussion-between-aravind-aravind-and-inbar-gazit).

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help you, you will need to contact customer support.

Comment: Ok, i generate again new RSA key and i pass, it working, thanks a lot, ik think  before generate RSA key, need to get consent , is it correct ? Anyway thanks a lot it working in production account also