# How Call DocuSign to create the envelope in production?

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

I am trying to call DocuSign to create the envelope in production and I am getting error as

```
 Error calling CreateEnvelope: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Code to call envelope

```
    Dim accessToken = AccessToken1 ' Access token using JWT
    Dim basePath = BasePath1 ' https://eu.docusign.net/restapi
    Dim accountId = AccountId1 ' AccountId1 from production login
    Dim env As EnvelopeDefinition = MakeEnvelope(Signer, DocusignCcAddress, Buffer, FileName)
   
    Dim apiClient = New ApiClient(basePath)
    apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
    Dim envelopesApi As EnvelopesApi = New EnvelopesApi(apiClient)
    Dim results As EnvelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, env) ' here i get that error
    Return results
```

When U use basepath URL as  "https://docusign.net/restapi" I am getting this error

> Error calling CreateEnvelope: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I used following code to get access token successfully

```
        Dim apiClient = New ApiClient("https://eu.docusign.net/restapi")
        Dim ik As String = odjDTRep.Rows(0)("iss_Int_Key").ToString()
        Dim userId As String = odjDTRep.Rows(0)("sub1_Api_UserName").ToString()

        Dim authserver As String = odjDTRep.Rows(0)("aud").ToString()
        Dim rsaKey As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("") & "/Key/KMKey.key")


        Dim scopes = New List(Of String) From {
        "signature"
    }
        Dim authToken As OAuth.OAuthToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(ik, userId, authserver, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsaKey), 1, scopes)
        Dim accessToken As String = authToken.access_token
```

Comment: You already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618566/how-to-obtain-access-token-using-production-environment-in-docusign/71623053?noredirect=1#comment126595706_71623053

Comment: How is this one any different?

Comment: yes, that is obtain access token in production account, now above question is how to call docusing envelope in production account.
I get access token using jwt as i mentions above in description and also i form a envelope like signer,Carbon copy ,signing position,but when i call create i got that error.In EnvelopesApi  class i pass apiclient and try to get result using EnvelopeSummary   i got error.
 Dim results As EnvelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, env)

Comment: Please leave @James' edit be - it was a good amendment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the baseURL for your production account. It is not the same for all customers, so you have to retrieve it using [getUserInformation()](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) command.

You can also find your baseURL on the [Apps and Keys page](https://admin.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=appsAndKeys) if you go there at the top.

Comment: yes, from account under Apps and Keys page my base uri is https://eu.docusign.net, still same problem , need to pass https://eu.docusign.net or https://eu.docusign.net/restapi ?
 for  Dim apiClient = New ApiClient(basePath)
    apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)

Comment: with the /restapi, yes. did you try that?

Comment: yes i tried both with and without /restapi, same problem , code Ss -https://prnt.sc/WZ1Wj_zK9ii_   , when i get access token that time also changed base uri

Comment: what is the accountId you send to this method?

Comment: Can you check the value of AccountId1 ?

Comment: yes now working , i read from table and got space at the end for AccountId, now i put trim and works well.Thanks a lot